# Androld Webview Loading time issue

Tags: android

Hey i am facing loading time issue i am using this code i tried mostly things but still problem is same.Even if i will load amazon site then it will take 10 minute to upload

```
package com.example.app;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import com.example.app.BookMyShow.myWebClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MakeMyTrip extends Activity {
    private WebView mWebView;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "LoginPrefs";
    SharedPreferences settings;
    String query="http://freekabalance.blogspot.in";
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.freekabalance);
      settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
      editor = settings.edit();      
      progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
      mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);


      WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
      webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      mWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
      mWebView.loadUrl(query);


  }

  public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient

  {

   @Override

   public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

   }

   @Override

   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    view.loadUrl(url);

    return true;



   }



   @Override

   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

   }

  }



  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
      if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
          mWebView.goBack();
          return;
      }

      // Otherwise defer to system default behavior.
      super.onBackPressed();
  }
}
```

I tried this also but it's not working

```
mWebView.setInitialScale(1);
  mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize( 5 * 1024 * 1024 ); // 5MB
  mWebView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(     getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() );
  mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess( true );
  mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
  mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT );

  mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
  mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

I tried this also but it is not working

```
 webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
  webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
  webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
  webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it helped me:

```
webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
}       
else {
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guest you don't want to handle special url format, so you don't need to call `view.loadUrl(url)` inside method `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`,

```
@Override

public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

    return true;

}
```